# How can I search a CSV file for a value, then get another value associated with it?

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed, csv

#### myfile.csv

```
445,aLabel
446,anotherLabel
447,aThirdLabel
```

In a bash script, I want to search for the presence of "anotherLabel"
(in a case-insensitive way) within myfile.csv and get the value 446. 
Additionally, if "anotherLabel" isn't present, I want to add it to the end, incrementing the token of the previous line by 1.

I started with the `if` statement:

```
if grep -Fiq anotherLabel myfile.csv; then
    #get the value of field 1 (446 in this example) and store it in a variable
else
    #increment the last value of field 1 present in the file and store it in a variable
    #and append "448,anotherLabel" to myfile.csv
fi
```

I'm not sure that using grep to verify whether the label is even in the file
is the best way to approach this
or if there is an easier method using sed or awk.

Comment: Maybe instead of saying "446" as if it's static, say "the value of field 1".  For the "else" case where "anotherLabel" does not exist, do you need to set a variable?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the suggestions. In the else case, I do need to process the uninitialized value of anotherLabel, but i also want to add it to the file in case i ever need to look it up again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
 awk -F',' '{ if ($2 == "anotherLabel") { print $1 } }' myfile.csv
```

Comment: It works, but looking something more robust, like if...else implementation. Also case insensitive checking

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` and `tail`:

```
search="anotherLabel"
file=myfile.csv

if value=$(grep -Pio -m1 "^[0-9]+(?=,$search$)" "$file"); then
    echo "do something with $value"
elif lastvalue=$(tail -n1 "$file" | grep -o '^[0-9]\+'); then
    # append lastvalue + 1 and search string
    echo "$((++lastvalue)),$search" >> "$file"
else
    # handle error
    echo "error. no integer value in last line of \"$file\" found." >&2
fi
```

In the first `grep` the following options are used:

- `-P` enable Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE) to use a positive lookahead (see below).
- `-i` ignore case in pattern
- `-o` only print the matching part of the line
- `-m1` stop after the first match

The first regex `^[0-9]+(?=,$search$)` is using a positive lookahead `(?=pattern)` to match a number followed by `,` and the search string without comma and search string being part of the match itself.
In combination with option `-o` only the matching part (the number) is printed.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do this in pure bash:

```
file="myfile.csv"
seek="anotherLabel"
while IFS=, read id label; do
    if [[ $label == "$seek" ]]; then
        myid=$id
        break
    fi
    lastid=$id
done < "$file"
if [[ -z $myid ]]; then
    myid=$((lastid + 1))
    echo "$myid,$seek" >> "$file"
fi
echo "$seek id is: $myid"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
$ awk -v tgt='the string you want to find' '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    tolower($2) == tolower(tgt) { print $1 | "cat>&2"; f=1 }
    { print; p=$1 }
    END { if (!f) { print ++p, tgt; print p | "cat>&2"} exit !f }
' file
```

For example:

```
$ var=$( { awk -v tgt='anotherLabel' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} tolower($2) == tolower(tgt){print $1 | "cat>&2"; f=1} {print; p=$1} END {if (!f) { print ++p, tgt; print p | "cat>&2"} exit !f}' file > out1; } 2>&1 )
$ echo "exit status: $?, value found: $var"
exit status: 0, value found: 446
$ cat out1
445,aLabel
446,anotherLabel
447,aThirdLabel

$ var=$( { awk -v tgt='missingLabel' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} tolower($2) == tolower(tgt){print $1 | "cat>&2"; f=1} {print; p=$1} END {if (!f) { print ++p, tgt; print p | "cat>&2"} exit !f}' file > out1; } 2>&1 )
$ echo "exit status: $?, value found: $var"
exit status: 1, value found: 448
$ cat out1
445,aLabel
446,anotherLabel
447,aThirdLabel
448,missingLabel
```

The above will print any $1 that matches a $2 or is newly added to the end of the file to stderr (which is then captured in a variable, "var") set the exit status to success if the target string was found, failure otherwise, and print the whole file to stdout with the missing value added if appropriate.

Comment: Ed: awk can write to file directly  `printf (...) >> ARGV[1]` for the first file used, or ARGIND in gawk for an arbitrary list of files. Using stderr looks a lot more complex.

Comment: You mean from the END section, right? If so that's true, I just generally avoid writing to the file I'm reading unless absolutely necessary and I've thought through all of the scenarios that might end up corrupting the input file. I agree using stderr in this case is probably more complex than necessary (though I haven't thought through all possible scenarios), just force of habit as it will work in all cases.

Comment: @Isaac one example just occurred to me of a problem scenario for writing to ARGV[1]: if the input file isn't writable then the script outputs the number it tried to add as if it had added it but the resulting file doesn't have the new line added to it. It's these kind of edge cases that make me try to keep the file manipulation (which files get modified and how THOSE errors get handled) in shell and the text manipulation (what text gets changed and how THOSE errors are handled) in awk as much as possible.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation, much apreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but on testing, if the file is not-writable, awk emits a clear and fatal error (no more input will be processed). Can't think of a case were this is not enough. Care to review? @EdMorton

Comment: My point was that if you write to a new file then you get the desired output while if you try to write to an unwritable file then you don't. Also if the directory is unwritable then directing to a new file will fail before awk runs rather than aborting while it's running. In both cases trying to write an an ARGV[1] that's not writable could abort the execution after potentially having written partial results to other files in writable locations. Directing to a new file produces a preferable result in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

The following awk code does what you ask for:

```
#!/bin/bash

filetosearch=myfile.csv
searchString=${1:-anotherLabel}

awk -F',' -v pat="$searchString" '
BEGIN{patl=tolower(pat);flag=0};
{prev=$1}(tolower($0)==patl){flag=1;exit}
END{
     if(flag){
          print prev
             }else{
          printf("%s%s%s\n", prev+1,FS,pat) >> ARGV[1]    # use ARGIND in gawk.
          print prev+1
             }
   }' "${filetosearch}"
```

Search for an string `"${searchString}"` that exactly match a full line (change `tolower($0)==patl` to `tolower($0)~patl` to match more loosely) and reports at which index it was found. If the string is not matched, it is added (appended) to the file used with an index that is one more than the last index of the file.

Example:

```
$ ./script aLabel
445

$ ./script anotherLabel
446

$ ./script MissingLabel
450

$ cat myfile.csv
445,aLabel
446,anotherLabel
447,aThirdLabel
448,dhdhdhdhdhd
449,anotherLabel4646
450,MissingLabel
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make this a little shorter
if you took out the diagnostics and error-handling:

```
file="myfile.csv"
label="$1"
if [ "$label" != "" ]
then
        IFS="," read val1 val2 <<< "$(awk -F, -v look4="$label" \
                'tolower($2) == tolower(look4) { found=1; print $1 "," $2; }
                        END { if (!found) print $1; }' "$file")"
        if [ "$val2" != "" ]
        then
                echo "Found value $val1 with label $val2."
        else
                val1=$((val1+1))
                if printf "%s,%s\n" "$val1" "$label" >> "$file"
                then
                        echo "Added value $val1 to file for label $label."
                else
                        echo "Failed to add value $val1 to file."
                fi
        fi
else
        echo "Missing label."
        exit
fi
```

This builds on [Bart’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/527495/80216#527499),
using `awk` to compare the second field (`$2`) in each line
to the desired label, but makes the test case-insensitive. 
After the above code runs,
`$var1` will contain the value that corresponds to `$label`,
one way or the other. 
If `$var2` is not blank, then it contains the *exact* label that was found. 
If `$var2` is blank,
the label was not found (and an attempt was made to add it to the file).

Answer (score 0):

I have done with below script

Let me know if there is any input

```
count=`awk '{print NR}' o.txt| awk '{print NR}'|sed -n '$p'`

for ((i=1;i<=$count;i++)); do sed -n ''$i'p' o.txt| grep "anotherLabel">/dev/null; if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then echo "anotherlabel exists"; awk -F "," -v i="$i"  'NR==i && $2 == "anotherLabel" {print $1}' o.txt; uni_anotherlabel=`sed -n ''$i'p' o.txt| grep "anotherLabel"| awk -F "," '{print $1}'`;else echo "anotherlabel doesnt exsists"; echo "$uni_anotherlabel"; fi; done
```

Comment: Ther's a LOT wrong with that script, you might want to run it through shellcheck and then test it.